# how can i write a before delete trigger in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers, delete-row

I have two tables
first{**orderID**,companyName,orderDate}
second {**orderID** , **employeeID** , employeeSalary }

I want to write a trigger that
when I delete a record from "first" all records in "second" with the same "orderID" value must be deleted

Comment: You don't need a trigger for that. Use Foreign Key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't wish to use the relation cascade delete :

```
  ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CascadeDelete]
  ON  [dbo].[first]
  AFTER  DELETE
  AS 
  BEGIN



   DELETE FROM second WHERE orderID IN
  (SELECT orderID FROM deleted )


  END
```